# What's the equivalent of PostMethod$addParameter() in http client 4.25

Tags: java, apache, http-post

i am moving some legacy code from apache commons http client (3.0.1) to http client 4.25, and no longer see the PostMethod$addParameter() methods for passing [name,value] pairs to the server....

it appears with http client 4.25 that i have to create some sort of HttpEntity, which i can then bind to my request using HttpPost$setEntity()....

in my case, i have a set of parameters whose values are (long!!) Base64 encoded text strings; so i don't want to send these parameters via the URL, but rather place them in the body of the request...

what's the basic idiom for doing this with http client 4.25???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See example:

```
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sub", data));          

        //httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

You can find doc for `NameValuePair` [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html)

Comment: Note to OP, `UrlEncodedFormEntity` is URL encoded but it will be written to the body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 4.3 one can also do

```
    HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create("POST")
            .addParameter("sub", "stuff")
            .build();
```

The business of constructing the right HTTP entity will be taken care of by the request builder.